# if checkbox is unchecked during form submission then it will become red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a register form and there I have two checkboxes. If it is unchecked and the client clicks on register button then it will become red.

Following is my checkbox codes:-

```js
$('#age_confirmation').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
    $('#age_confirmation').css('color', c);
});
$('#terms_of_service').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
    $('#terms_of_service').css('color', c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off">
  <div style="display:none"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10"/> Age Confirmation
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11"/> Terms of Service
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is this `<div style="display:none">` opened but not closed tag? Correct your markup pls.

Comment: Do you mean change color of sibling text of checkbox e.g **Age Confirmation**?

Comment: Smollet777 I changed it now check I forgot to add it in the question but it is in the code.

Comment: Mohammad that will work.

Comment: Defining positive tabindex value can cause problems. If you remove those tabindex values, experience will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap sibling text of input with `label` tag and on change of input change color of relevant label. Setting the color of a checkbox `input` does not affect the color of the text next to it.

```js
$('#age_confirmation').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
  $('#age_confirmation').next().css('color', c);
})
$('#terms_of_service').change(function(){
  var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
  $('#terms_of_service').next().css('color', c);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10"/> 
  <label for="age_confirmation">Age Confirmation</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11"/>
  <label for="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />
</form>
```

Also you can simplify your code

```js
$('#register :checkbox').change(function(){
  $(this).next().css('color', this.checked ? '' : 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10"/> 
  <label for="age_confirmation">Age Confirmation</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11"/>
  <label for="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Juan Mendes this code works but one problem as soon as the page is loaded the label is red I want it red when they click on the register button. but anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlekStephanok I think this is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/L5u6hzr8/

Comment: @juan no problem I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You're listening the `change` event on each checkbox. 
Reading your question, I think that you want to handle the form's `submit` event, and then provide some feedback to the user, something like...

EDIT: you will need to wrap the checkbox text in a `<label>` as well to see the color changing, as @Juan Mendes stated in his answer

```
<input id="age_confirmation" ...><label for="age_confirmation">Age</label>

<script>
const age = $('#age_confirmation');
const terms = $('#terms_of_service');
$('#register').submit(function() {
  age.next().css('color', age.checked ? '' : 'red');
  terms.next().css('color', terms.checked ? '' : 'red');
  return age.checked && terms.checked;
})
</script>
```

Comment: That may be true, but this doesn't solve the problem since you are still not setting the color of the text next to it which is the OP's real intention. Doing it on the submit is not the real problem.

Comment: during form submission... is probably secondary?

Comment: Yes, the primary concern is that the text is not turning red.

Comment: I think is both... listening the change doesn't solve the issue, because if the user never touch the checkbox, you'll see nothing

Comment: Owner's dixit: "this code works but one problem as soon as the page is loaded the label is red I want it red. I want it red when they click on the register button...". But nevermind...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check(){
if(document.getElementById("age_confirmation").checked ==false){
$("#lbl_age_confirmation").css("color","red");
}else{
$("#lbl_age_confirmation").css("color","black");
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off"><div >

<input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10"/> <lable id="lbl_age_confirmation">Age Confirmation</lable>

<input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11"/> Terms of Service

<input onclick="check()" type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />

</form>
```

Comment: You should explain what the difference is. What was wrong with the OP's code?

Comment: And <lable> is not even proper HTML.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, following changes has been made,

1. Added `Span` and `ID` in you checkbox text for text coloring.
2. Added `novalidate` attribute in form submission, as it was preventing the jQuery operation.

```js
$('#age_confirmation').change(function() {
  var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
  $('#age_confirmation_span').css('color', c);
});

$('#terms_of_service').change(function() {
  var c = this.checked ? '' : 'red';
  $('#terms_of_service_span').css('color', c);
});

$("#register").submit(function() {
  var returnStatus = true;
  if ($('#age_confirmation').is(":checked") == true) {
    $('#age_confirmation_span').css('color', '');
  } else {
    $('#age_confirmation_span').css('color', 'red');
    returnStatus = false;
  }
  if ($('#terms_of_service').is(":checked") == true) {
    $('#terms_of_service_span').css('color', '');
  } else {
    $('#terms_of_service_span').css('color', 'red');
    returnStatus = false;
  }
  return returnStatus;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off" novalidate>

  <input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10" /><span id="age_confirmation_span"> Age Confirmation</span>

  <input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11" /><span id="terms_of_service_span"> Terms of Service</span>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use CSS selectors and a little of JS.
First of all, you'll need to wrap your text in order to affect the color, as was told by others users here...

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-signin form-register" role="form" id="register" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="checkbox" id="age_confirmation" name="age_confirmation" required tabindex="10"/>
   <label for="age_confirmation">Age Confirmation</label>

   <input type="checkbox" id="terms_of_service" name="terms_of_service" required tabindex="11"/>
   <label for="terms_of_service">Terms of Service</label>

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-tiffany" value="register" />
</form>
```

Then you can select all the `label` next to an `invalid input` using pure CSS:

```
 :invalid + label {
   color: red;
 }
```

But this will select the labels before you press the submit button.
So, we'll use javascript to append a class to identify a `submitting` state...

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  $('#register').addClass('submitting');
});
```

And then we can match this using CSS...

```
.submitting :invalid + label {
  color: red;
}
```

You'll find a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yL7je0ap/

### Advantages of this solution

- Keeps a clean separation between CSS and JS
- Uses the built-in HTML5 validation feature
- Doesn't need to listen every change

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with JavaScript, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(form){
        if (form.agreement.checked==false){
            alert("Please agree to our Terms and Conditons."); //Here you can do some styling
            //document.getElementById('terms_of_service').classList.add('redColor')
            return false;
        }else{
            //document.getElementById('terms_of_service').classList.add('whiteColor')
        }
    }
</script>
```